# not being able to use a js library.(net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found))

Tags: javascript, wordpress, npm, import

Hi when try to import kuroshiro into my main js file. i get this error : Failed to resolve module specifier "kuroshiro". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../ with the code below. I copied the code below from https://github.com/hexenq/kuroshiro. however it doesnt work.

```
import Kuroshiro from "kuroshiro";
// Initialize kuroshiro with an instance of analyzer (You could check the [apidoc](#initanalyzer) for more information):
// For this example, you should npm install and import the kuromoji analyzer first
import KuromojiAnalyzer from "kuroshiro-analyzer-kuromoji";
// Instantiate
const kuroshiro = new Kuroshiro();
// Initialize
// Here uses async/await, you could also use Promise
await kuroshiro.init(new KuromojiAnalyzer());
// Convert what you want
const result = await kuroshiro.convert("感じ取れたら手");
```

the next thing i did is to put the exact path of folder ./ / before "./jsfiles/kuroshiro". to see what i get. however i get another error saying ERR_ABORTED;
[image]

I first install kuroshiro by doing npm install kuroshiro  and install kuroshiro-analyzer-kuromoji. then next thing i copied the dist folder that was inside node_modules folder. to outside. because i want to use kuroshiro library on front-end; i did what kuroshiro documentation was telling me to do. but im not sure what im doing wrong.

this is my main file (i put on footer)

```
<script type="module" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/colorswebsite/script.js?ver=1.0.0"></script>
```

then i included the kuroshiro js files on the head.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//localhost:3000/wordpress/wp-content/themes/colorswebsite/jsfiles/kuroshiro.min.js?ver=1.0.0" id="kuroshiro-min-js-js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//localhost:3000/wordpress/wp-content/themes/colorswebsite/jsfiles/kuroshiro-analyzer-kuromoji.min.js?ver=1.0.0" id="kuroshiro-js-js"></script>
```

on github repo its saying to (build it from source with npm run build) i dont what it means.
[image][image]

this is my network tab

Comment: remove imports from your js file

Comment: @Mike I removed it but it saying Kuroshiro is not a constructor

Comment: make sure kuroshiro scripts have been loaded, look in devtools network tab, maybe there are some other errors in the console

Comment: @Mike i paste the screen shot of the networktab . the staus is 200 . its the first line .

Comment: I cannot see kuroshiro.min.js in the screenshot