# how to install js library? how to use js library and implement it on project

Tags: javascript, wordpress, npm, command

hi im trying to install kuroshiro js library but really new to this . i dont know how i can install this kuroshiro libray i read and did what was written on the documentaion. can anyone help me or give me the right direction to implement this library on my project?  i want to use it on the front-end side.
[enter link description here](https://github.com/hexenq/kuroshiro)

if u look on the documentation part it saying

Browser
Add dist/kuroshiro.min.js to your frontend project (you may first build it from source with npm run build after npm install), and in your HTML:

but i dont know what this actually means. it saying to add dist/kuroshiro.min.js on my frontend project. but when i added there error not found on console. also what should i do with npm run build ? here is a screenshot of the github documentation.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [not being able to use a js library.(net::ERR\_ABORTED 404 (Not Found))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73182535/not-being-able-to-use-a-js-library-neterr-aborted-404-not-found)

Comment: @lalaluka no it didnt answer my question.